# StoreKit 2 - Product request always empty

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I'm trying to fetch the products from the `App Store Connect` using `StoreKit 2` but always returns an empty array:

```json
let keys = [
    "com.app.suscripcion.mes.1"
]
        
let storeProducts = try await Product.products(for: keys)
```

I had added a key on the `InApp Purchase` section:

[image]

What do I have to do to fetch the products from the `App Store Connect`? If I use a `.storekit` configuration file it works but with a real scenario doesn't work

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to help you out. Are you getting errors? What does you actual code look like? [This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_a_store_in_your_app_using_the_storekit_api) might help with the setup. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum I get the code from the source code you share. Also in the Apple documentation doesn't say more about how to fetch the products from App Store Connect using StoreKit 2. I share the minimal reproducible example because there is no more code to use to reproduce the error.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you find out the cause of the problem?

Comment: @DPR The Account Holder needs to add a Bank Account on AppStore Connect and accept all the agreements it need

Comment: @pableiros You just saved me countless hours of debugging. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To solve this problem, the `Account Holder` from `App Store Connect`, inside `Agreements, Tax, and Banking`, needs to `Set Up Tax and Banking` to Paid Apps in order to get the InApp Purchase products from `App Store Connect`:

[image]

After that, the Status for the Paid Apps Type need to change to `Active` in order to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the StoreKit Configuration value is set to none in the options of the scheme that was executed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're passing the identifier of the **Product** or **Subscription** in this method and not the app's bundle identifier by mistake:

`try await Product.products(for: ["my_monthly_subscription"])` ✅

`try await Product.products(for: ["com.mycompany.myapp"])` ❌